# Angular - Adding an input's value with a number from $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-value, angularjs-bindings

I have the following code:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <input class="amount" type="text" name="" value="" />
        <input class="result" type="text" name="" value=""/>
</div>
```

I want to take a numerical value from $scope and add it to a number entered by a user in the input with class "amount" and display the result in the input with class "result". So, basically, the variable is defined in the **MainController** function as the following:

```
$scope.cost = 100;
```

I'm a bit confused as to what the best way is to do this, I see there are **ng-value** and **ng-model** directives at my disposal but I am having a hard time understanding which is the right one for this application (and how to properly use them).

Comment: you should use `ng-model="cost"` that will two way binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your application is asking for an inputs and they are going to submit there values OR gonna store it somewhere in DB. So `ng-model` (two way binding) will suits you application, which will update the value on `model` & `view` both.

**Markup**

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
    <input class="amount" type="text" ng-model="cost"/>
</div>
```

Above field will pre-populated as `100` and as you update it will also change `$scope.cost` value and the value if it is displayed on view anywhere.

Don't think about the `ng-value` that is only one way sort of binding. You can assign the value to input using `ng-value="cost"` that will only update the value attribute of `input` but when you update input from html you will never get those changes reflected inside `cost` scope variable as `ng-value` is meant for single way binding. Thinks like you should use use `ng-value` only when you want to display a value.

Comment: im not looking to have the input pre-populated with the 'cost' - rather - i'd like to take that 'cost' and add it to the number entered in the input (and then display this somewhere else).  So, according to your (awesome) explanation, I think i might actually want ng-value.

Again, I dont want to change the cost in the scope for this application.  I want to see how many items the user wants and then fetch the price and display the result in the other input. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Moose yes..you should use `ng-value` then..I covered this point in my explaination already..

Comment: okay so i would need to take that ng-value of 'cost' and do something like this: <input class="result" value="{{ whateverTheUserEnteredIntoTheAmountInput + cost }}".....  that's where I'm confused.  How do I take the value entered by the user and add it to the cost?  I get that we can pull in the cost by using ng-value but that's slightly different than what i need.

Comment: I think you want to display the addition somewhere on html with user entered value and cost..so then the html would be `<input class="result" ng-model="whateverTheUserEnteredIntoTheAmountInput"/>` then wherever you want to show addition you could use this `{{ whateverTheUserEnteredIntoTheAmountInput + cost }}` basically you need to use combination of both

Comment: OH! I get it now that totally makes sense.... I'll try this soon and let you know how it works out!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ng-model`

- **ng-value** : Its a directive useful for evaluating expression and the value is bound to $scope used for evaluating expressions
- **ng-model** : helps in  two-way data binding ,view-->controller and vice versa moreover its a directive  binds  the value of HTML controls